# Disable windows 10 rescaling for xna/monogame

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, resolution, monogame

I am having a problem with monogame. Currently I read the resolution like so:

```
public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        gameState = new GameState(All_Textures, AllSpritefontTexts, oldState, oldMouse); //All textures have a key, with as return: texture, starting point, clickarea
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        oldState = Keyboard.GetState();
        oldMouse = Mouse.GetState();
        IsMouseVisible = true; //You can see the cursor
        //graphics.IsFullScreen = true;                                                                //DISABLED FOR DEVELOPING REASONS
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height; //Set xna resolution height to curr screen resolution
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width;   //Set xna resolution width to curr screen resolution
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
    }
```

With this I continued to work on my project, and recently started testing my game on other computers. A lot of computers have a windows 10 magnification on, like seen in the image.
[image]

This results in my monogame images and spritefonts being misplaced and overlapping eachother, let alone my generated hitboxes. My question is:'How can I disable this magnification programatically in monogame?'

If you need more code to see before you can answer my question, my entire application is found here https://github.com/FireStormHR/SeriousGaming

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to set the resolution to the size of your screen, rather than your viewport. If the resolution of the default render target is larger than the viewport, it will not draw properly. The viewport can't be larger than your screen.
Using GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width and GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height for the width and height will give the desired result.